# Using Ansible jinja2 list feature returns more that the list with ansible hostvars

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to use ansible hostvars to select a group of disks, here is my code:

```
- name: Output disk information
  debug:
    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'nvme.*') | select('string') | list
```

What I expect is a list of devices beginning with `nvme` or an empty list, but I get the `var:` value (query if you will) back as well as the list:

```
ok: [cm42.ag6hq.net] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'nvme.*') | select('string') | list": [
        "nvme0n1"
    ]
}
ok: [cm43.ag6hq.net] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'nvme.*') | select('string') | list": []
}
```

What I expected back was:

```
ok: [cm42.ag6hq.net] => {
    [
        "nvme0n1"
    ]
}
ok: [cm43.ag6hq.net] => {
    []
}
```

So when I use this query within the `with_items:` context, it tries to process the whole query, not the resulting list (which is what I expected):

```
failed: [cm42.ag6hq.net] (item=hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'nvme.*') | select('string') | list) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'nvme.*') | select('string') | list", "msg": "Device /dev/hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'nvme.*') | select('string') | list not found."}
```

Where am I going off the rails here?

Comment: That's just the output from debug, showing the var you requested (in this case, an expression), and the value. You haven't shown your loop declaration, but it sounds like you forgot the Jinja delimiters (`{{` and `}}`) around the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I can simplify:
playbook:

```
    - name: Get list of NVMe block devices
      set_fact:
        nvme_devices: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_devices'] | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'match', '^nvme') | map(attribute='value') | list }}"

    - name: Create partitions on the NVMe disks
      parted:
        device: "/dev/{{ item }}"
        number: 1
        state: present
        align: optimal
        unit: "%"
        part_type: primary
        fs_type: ext4
      with_items: "{{ nvme_devices }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [Create partitions on the NVMe disks] *****************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [cm41.ag6hq.net] (item={'virtual': 1, 'links': {'ids': ['nvme-INTEL_SSDPEKNU010TZ_PHKA220103081P0B', 'nvme-eui.0000000001000000e4d25c78cf5e5501'], 'uuids': [], 'labels': [], 'masters': []}, 'vendor': None, 'model': 'INTEL SSDPEKNU010TZ', 'sas_address': None, 'sas_device_handle': None, 'serial': 'PHKA220103081P0B', 'removable': '0', 'support_discard': '512', 'partitions': {}, 'rotational': '0', 'scheduler_mode': 'none', 'sectors': '2000409264', 'sectorsize': '512', 'size': '953.87 GB', 'host': 'Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1aa (rev 03)', 'holders': []}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "err": "Error: Could not stat device /dev/{virtual: - No such file or directory.\n", "item": {"holders": [], "host": "Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1aa (rev 03)", "links": {"ids": ["nvme-INTEL_SSDPEKNU010TZ_PHKA220103081P0B", "nvme-eui.0000000001000000e4d25c78cf5e5501"], "labels": [], "masters": [], "uuids": []}, "model": "INTEL SSDPEKNU010TZ", "partitions": {}, "removable": "0", "rotational": "0", "sas_address": null, "sas_device_handle": null, "scheduler_mode": "none", "sectors": "2000409264", "sectorsize": "512", "serial": "PHKA220103081P0B", "size": "953.87 GB", "support_discard": "512", "vendor": null, "virtual": 1}, "msg": "Error while getting device information with parted script: '/usr/sbin/parted -s -m /dev/{'virtual': 1, 'links': {'ids': ['nvme-INTEL_SSDPEKNU010TZ_PHKA220103081P0B', 'nvme-eui.0000000001000000e4d25c78cf5e5501'], 'uuids': [], 'labels': [], 'masters': []}, 'vendor': None, 'model': 'INTEL SSDPEKNU010TZ', 'sas_address': None, 'sas_device_handle': None, 'serial': 'PHKA220103081P0B', 'removable': '0', 'support_discard': '512', 'partitions': {}, 'rotational': '0', 'scheduler_mode': 'none', 'sectors': '2000409264', 'sectorsize': '512', 'size': '953.87 GB', 'host': 'Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1aa (rev 03)', 'holders': []} -- unit '%' print'", "out": "", "rc": 1}
failed: [cm42.ag6hq.net] (item={'virtual': 1, 'links': {'ids': ['nvme-INTEL_SSDPEKNU010TZ_PHKA219401S71P0B', 'nvme-eui.0000000001000000e4d25cc6ae5c5501'], 'uuids': [], 'labels': [], 'masters': []}, 'vendor': None, 'model': 'INTEL SSDPEKNU010TZ', 'sas_address': None, 'sas_device_handle': None, 'serial': 'PHKA219401S71P0B', 'removable': '0', 'support_discard': '512', 'partitions': {}, 'rotational': '0', 'scheduler_mode': 'none', 'sectors': '2000409264', 'sectorsize': '512', 'size': '953.87 GB', 'host': 'Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1aa (rev 03)', 'holders': []}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "err": "Error: Could not stat device /dev/{virtual: - No such file or directory.\n", "item": {"holders": [], "host": "Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1aa (rev 03)", "links": {"ids": ["nvme-INTEL_SSDPEKNU010TZ_PHKA219401S71P0B", "nvme-eui.0000000001000000e4d25cc6ae5c5501"], "labels": [], "masters": [], "uuids": []}, "model": "INTEL SSDPEKNU010TZ", "partitions": {}, "removable": "0", "rotational": "0", "sas_address": null, "sas_device_handle": null, "scheduler_mode": "none", "sectors": "2000409264", "sectorsize": "512", "serial": "PHKA219401S71P0B", "size": "953.87 GB", "support_discard": "512", "vendor": null, "virtual": 1}, "msg": "Error while getting device information with parted script: '/usr/sbin/parted -s -m /dev/{'virtual': 1, 'links': {'ids': ['nvme-INTEL_SSDPEKNU010TZ_PHKA219401S71P0B', 'nvme-eui.0000000001000000e4d25cc6ae5c5501'], 'uuids': [], 'labels': [], 'masters': []}, 'vendor': None, 'model': 'INTEL SSDPEKNU010TZ', 'sas_address': None, 'sas_device_handle': None, 'serial': 'PHKA219401S71P0B', 'removable': '0', 'support_discard': '512', 'partitions': {}, 'rotational': '0', 'scheduler_mode': 'none', 'sectors': '2000409264', 'sectorsize': '512', 'size': '953.87 GB', 'host': 'Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1aa (rev 03)', 'holders': []} -- unit '%' print'", "out": "", "rc": 1}
```

It's evident by the `"Error: Could not stat device /dev/{virtual: - No such file or directory.\n"` error that `nvme_devices` is not a list of device names, but rather apparently the whole device (see `item='virtual...` in the output.

So why doesn't `"{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_devices'] | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'match', '^nvme') | map(attribute='value') | list }}"` create a list of names?

ANSWER:
because the map attribute is `'value'` and not `'key'`

`"{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_devices'] | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'match', '^nvme') | map(attribute='key') | list }}"` will create a list of names that begin with nvme.